# Nice sequence Algorithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms

I work on a problem for some hours and I don't really know how to get further.
A sequence of n integers is "nice" if the following conditions are satisfied:

```
1. 0 <= a[k] <= k-1
2. a[k] ≡ a[m] mod k for all pairs k, m such that k divides m
```

Now what i must do is verify if my array a contain any element equal with -1 and if it does, i must count all nice sequences that i can make by changing that -1.

I also verify this website and google and a lot more for some informations and i found this: [Questions about finite sequences of natural numbers with distinct partial sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13139/questions-about-finite-sequences-of-natural-numbers-with-distinct-partial-sums)

Maybe partial sums cand help me go further with this? Or any other advice?...

Thank you in advice!

Comment: Is the issue to do it, or to do it efficiently?

Comment: To do it, but I if it will be otpimized method it will be better

Comment: are you saying that if the sequence has $-1$, it needs to be changed and not treated as equal to $k-1$? What if the sequence does not have a $-1$? What if it has more than one $-1$? are we assuming the rest of the elements correctly meet the requirements between all their pairs?

Comment: If there is -1, we must change the value of -1 to other which respect that 2 conditions. If the sequence does not have -1, that mean sequence is allready a "nice" sequence. If it has more than one -1, we must change every -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the $k$th element of the sequence is a residue modulo $k$, and must also be congruent to the $m$th element modulo $k$ if $k | m$.

For example if $a_m=a_{10}=-1$, then you need to find a new value of $a_{10}$ such that:

$a_1 \equiv a_{10} \bmod 1$

$a_2 \equiv a_{10} \bmod 2$

$a_5 \equiv a_{10} \bmod 5$

So just get the divisors of $m$ to determine which congruences you need to solve for, and then use the Chinese remainder theorem to get the value of $a_{m}$ modulo $m$.